# Extract lines containing a specific pattern for multiple and save the output to individual output files

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a folder with many `.vcf` files. I need to extract all the lines that begin with `#` and save them in a file and then append all the lines where the 12th column starts with `1/1` in the same file. It should create a new output file for each input file.

`abc.vcf`, `def.vcf` --> filter --> `abcfiltered.vcf`, `deffiltered.vcf`

I thought something like that but doesn't work:

```bash
printf '%s\0' *.vcf | xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c 'grep "#" "$1" > "candilist${1#case*}"' sh
```

this works for the first condition

I tried to add this command

```
awk -F '\t' '$12~/^1/' "$1");
```

using them separately works, but together doesn't. I guess is something with quotes or brackets.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'\t' '
    /^#/          { print >"file1" }
    ($12 ~/^1\/1/){ print >"file2" }' ./*.vcf
```

this will save lines from all .vcf files which those starts with character *`#`* into *file1* and lines that column#12 starts with *`1/1`* (slash in regex in awk is a special character which we escaped that with a backslash) into separate *file2*.

Note that in the above code *file2* will contains both lines types (start with `#` and also column#12 starts with `1/1`); if want exclude *file2* from the lines start with `#`, add `next` statement in the first block `/^#/{ print >"file1"; next }`.

Also note that the priority is with the lines that starts with `#` since it's checking at first so if a line both conditions were meet only the first one will be considered, if you need that to be checked as second priority re-order the blocks.

---

Answer to thr revised question (process every .vcf file with generating outputs seperatly):

```
for file in ./*.vcf; do
    awk -F'\t' '
        /^#/          { print >(FILENAME"_1.procced") }
        ($12 ~/^1\/1/){ print >(FILENAME"_2.procced") }' "$file"
done
```

Comment: @wildos you are welcome! please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).